# How to use native popcount with numba

Tags: python, llvm, numba

I am using numba 0.57.1 and I would like to exploit the native CPU popcount in my code. My existing code is too slow as I need to run it hundreds of millions of times. Here is a MWE:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(nb.uint64(nb.uint64))
def popcount(x): 
      b=0
      while(x > 0):
          x &= x - nb.uint64(1)   
          b+=1
      return b
    
    
print(popcount(43))
```

The current speed is:

```
%timeit popcount(255)
148 ns ± 0.369 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

I believe that it should be possible to use the native CPU popcount (_mm_popcnt_u64 as a C intrinsic) instruction using [numba intrinsics](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/high-level.html#implementing-intrinsics) but this area is new to me.  The llvm intrinsic I need to use is, I think, [ctpop](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-ctpop-intrinsic). Assuming this is right, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
import numba as nb
from numba import types
from numba.cpython import mathimpl
from numba.extending import intrinsic


@intrinsic
def popcnt(typingctx, src):
    sig = types.uint64(types.uint64)

    def codegen(context, builder, signature, args):
        return mathimpl.call_fp_intrinsic(builder, "llvm.ctpop.i64", args)

    return sig, codegen


@nb.njit(nb.uint64(nb.uint64))
def popcount(x):
    return popcnt(x)


print(popcount(43))
```

Prints:

```
4
```

Comment: @Simd But, running a benchmark between normal njit function and function using intrinsic, the results are the same (I'm suspecting llvm already optimizes the `popcount()` function using the intrinsic, but YMMV).

Comment: Hmm... that is mysterious as the intrinsics version should just be using one CPU instruction, not a loop as in my posted code. You can see the assembly with popcount.inspect_asm() but I can't interpret it.

Comment: @Simd Yes, but LLVM compiler is so advanced, that it analyzes your function and *figures* out it's just popcount, so it replaces it with intrinsic. You can compile the functions with AOT and debug them (to see what actually happens): https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html#compiling-code-ahead-of-time

Comment: This is the assembly for the loop version https://bpa.st/66DQ . It does include popcntq %rdx, %rax in it! Specifically the code the runs seems to actually be " popcntq %rdx, %rax
 movq %rax, (%rdi)
 xorl %eax, %eax
 retq"

Comment: The two pieces of code do genuinely seem to be compiled to the same assembly by numba which is borderline miraculous and also frustrating that I can't speed it up.